# Unable to sign in to Google from the GooglePlusSample code using GooglePlusPlatform

Tags: ios, google-plus, keychain

I am running the GooglePlusPlatform Sample Code provided by Google to learn about its SDk. However, when I run the application and click on the sign-in button it generates an error as:

> Error Domain=com.google.GooglePlusPlatform Code=-1 "keychain error"
>   UserInfo=0x1100bdd0 {NSLocalizedDescription=keychain error}

Same error also occurs in another application I have created which uses the GooglePlus Sign in. I Googled about it, but could not find anything useful. Please help!

Comment: What are the results of the error?

Comment: yes the error is resolved.. the clientID i created for my project in Google's developer page was registered using an expired email-id.. replacing the email-id worked for me.. To create a client id and register your project you would need to visit [link](https://console.developers.google.com/project)
thank you :)

Answer (score 5):

Go to TARGETS > Capabilities > and enable "KeyChain Sharing".

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I actually filed this bug on the Google Services GitHub repo, and got responses from the coders sayings that it´s an Apple Bug and there´s nothing they can do about it.

https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/issues/82

Good news is, that the problem only happens when Xcode is attached to the phone. It works fine otherwise. So even though it's a pain to test, we shouldn't worry about it being a problem for end users. (fingers crossed)

Answer (score 1):

I see this is not happening in simulator. And on real devices, this happens only when exception break point is created. Just remove that break point and try. It should work.